# How to provide parameters defined at the source asset declaration to the IO Manager?

Tags: python, dagster

So my initial task was to create an IO Manager that should connect to a database and return data as pandas dataframe.

(I am using dagster 1.3.10)

### Design

IMO, the credentials (ip, port, user, password) must be parameters of the IO manager because I want different resources for different credentials.
But the other interesting parameters that can be used to perform a database query (select fields, optional filters, sorting, limit, ...) should be linked to an asset definition.

I had no trouble creating the credentials parameter, like this:

```py
@io_manager(
    config_schema={
        'ip': Field(str, is_required=True),
        'port': Field(int, default_value=5432),
        'username': Field(str, is_required=True),
        'password': Field(str, is_required=True)
    }
)
def database_io_manager(init_context):
    return DatabaseIOManager(
        ip=init_context.resource_config.get('ip'),
        port=init_context.resource_config.get('port'),
        username=init_context.resource_config.get('username'),
        password=init_context.resource_config.get('password'),
    )
```

Then I can just provide this function in the resources dict that I provide to definitions

```py
defs = Definitions(resources={'database_io_manager': database_io_manager})
```

So now I can use this IO manager in my assets definitions

```py
@asset(io_manager_key='database_io_manager')
def my_asset():
    pass
```

Now like I said, I want the query parameters to be at the asset level, so I've created a configuration.

```py
from dagster import Config
import pydantic
class DatabaseConfig(Config):
    fields: List[str] = pydantic.Field()
```

I provide this configuration to the asset in the `metadata` attribute.

```py
asset(io_manager_key='database_io_manager',metadata={'io_manager': DatabaseConfig(fields='*')})
def my_asset():
    pass
```

And I can use this in my IO manager with a custom method

```py
 def load_metadata(self, context: Union[InputContext, OutputContext]) -> None:
        config: DatabaseConfig = context.metadata.get("io_manager")
        if not isinstance(config, DatabaseConfig):
            raise ValueError('wrong config type')
        self.fields = config.fields
```

### Problem

This work with `Asset` but not with `SourceAsset`.

If I define a source asset like this:

```py
my_source_asset = SourceAsset(
    key='my_source_asset',
    io_manager_key='database_io_manager',
    metadata=DatabaseConfig(fields='*')
)
```

I can see the metadata associated with this source asset in dagit, but when effectively loading the asset, the metadata dict is empty.

Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

### Other (minor) problems

#### unserializable

I tried to provide a minimal replication example and in the process of doing so I encountered other issues.

The first that bugs me is that this `DatabaseConfig` object is not displayed by dagit. It says 'unserializable'. But I am extending the `Config` class and I've tested to call the `json()` method on it and it works well.

Bonus 1: What can I do to make the `DatabaseConfig` class serializable as dagit wants it?

#### zero io manager use

With the code that can be found at the end of this question, when I look in dagit I have zero use of my io managers.
[image: zero uses]

Bonus 2: Why can't I see the IO managers uses ?

---

```py
# minimal_example_bug_dagster.py
from __future__ import annotations
import pickle
from typing import Union
import pydantic

from dagster import (
    Config,
    Definitions,
    InputContext,
    OutputContext,
    SourceAsset,
    asset,
    IOManager,
    fs_io_manager,
    io_manager,
)


class CustomIOConfig(Config):
    custom_file_name: str = pydantic.Field()


class CustomIOManager(IOManager):
    my_attribute: str = None

    def get_key(self, context: Union[InputContext, OutputContext]) -> str:
        return context.asset_key.path[:-1]

    def load_metadata(self, context: Union[InputContext, OutputContext]) -> None:
        context.log.info(context.metadata)
        config: CustomIOConfig = context.metadata.get("io_manager")
        self.my_attribute = config.custom_file_name

    def load_input(self, context: InputContext) -> str:
        context.log.info(f"Inside load_input for {self.get_key(context)}")
        self.load_metadata(context)
        pickle.load(open(self.my_attribute, "rb"))

    def handle_output(self, context: "OutputContext", obj: str) -> None:
        context.log.info(f"Inside handle_output for {self.get_key(context)}")
        self.load_metadata(context)
        pickle.dump(obj, open(self.my_attribute, "wb"))


@asset(
    metadata={"io_manager": CustomIOConfig(custom_file_name="foo")},
    io_manager_key="custom_io_manager",
)
def my_asset():
    return "Hello"


my_source_asset = SourceAsset(
    "my_source_asset",
    metadata={"io_manager": CustomIOConfig(custom_file_name="bar")},
    io_manager_key="custom_io_manager",
)


@asset(io_manager_key="fs_io_manager")
def using_both_assets(my_asset, my_source_asset):
    return f"{my_asset}, {my_source_asset}"


@io_manager
def custom_io_manager(init_context):
    return CustomIOManager()


defs = Definitions(
    assets=[my_asset, my_source_asset, using_both_assets],
    resources={"fs_io_manager": fs_io_manager, "custom_io_manager": custom_io_manager},
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to use the context property `upstream_output` to retrieve the metadata.

```py
class CustomIOConfig(Config):
    custom_file_name: str = pydantic.Field()

class CustomIOManager(IOManager):
    my_attribute: str = None

    def load_metadata(self, context: Union[InputContext, OutputContext]) -> None:
        config: CustomIOConfig = context.upstream_output.metadata.get("io_manager")
        self.my_attribute = config.custom_file_name
    
@asset(
    metadata={"io_manager": CustomIOConfig(custom_file_name="foo")},
    io_manager_key="custom_io_manager",
)
def my_asset():
    return "Hello"
```